# SQL JOIN ON a table name equal to a field value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I'm looking for a mysql query (using php) to go through each table one at a time and only display all results that don't match the date of the key in the t_lastmod table. I'm not sure how to say ON tablename = field value.

**t_one**

```
guid | name | lastmod
 1   |  Joe | 2012-01-01 01:00:00
 2   |  Tom | 2012-01-02 01:00:00
 3   |  Sue | 2012-03-01 02:00:00
```

**t_two**

```
guid | pet  | lastmod
 4   | cat  | 2012-01-01 01:00:00
 5   | dog  | 2012-01-02 01:00:00
 6   | fish | 2012-03-01 02:00:00
```

**t_three**

```
guid | fruit   | lastmod
 7   |  orange | 2012-01-01 01:00:00
 8   |  pear   | 2012-01-02 01:00:00
 9   |  grape  | 2012-03-01 02:00:00
```

**t_lastmod**

```
table_name | lastmod
   t_one   |  2012-01-01 01:00:00
   t_two   |  2012-01-02 01:00:00
   t_three |  2012-01-01 02:00:00
```

**The query results would be:**

```
t_one => 2 | Tom   | 2012-01-02 01:00:00
t_one => 3 | Sue   | 2012-03-01 02:00:00
t_two => 4 | cat   | 2012-01-01 01:00:00
t_two => 6 | fish  | 2012-03-01 02:00:00
t_three => 8 | pear | 2012-01-02 01:00:00
t_three => 9 | grape | 2012-03-01 02:00:00
```

My code so far (need help on the JOIN t_lastmod ON...)

```
$tables = array('t_one', 't_two', 't_three');

  foreach ($tables AS $table) {

    $query = " select $table.* from $table JOIN t_lastmod ON $table = t_lastmod.TABLE_NAME WHERE $table.lastmod != t_lastmod.lastmod ";

  }
```

Comment: What is the current output of the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select $table.* 
from $table 
JOIN t_lastmod ON '$table' = t_lastmod.TABLE_NAME 
WHERE $table.lastmod != t_lastmod.lastmod "
```

Comment: put single quote around $table in ON clause.